# Geometry Nodes: How do I write a boolean TRUE value only for a certain specific vertex or point?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I write a boolean TRUE value only for a certain specific vertex or point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way, store a boolean attribute for a selected point:

[image]